# How many = signs are required to equal a value in php?

Tags: php

I have following code which is not working with three equal signs (===). Hence it is working with single equal sign (=). I always use === in such cases and that works fine. I am confused why it is not working in this case?

```
$vendor_name = "Stock Returned";
if($vendor_name = "Stock Returned")
{
    $stock_return === "Yes";
}
else
{
    $stock_return = "No";
}
echo $stock_return;
```

Result of above code is showing "No". But in my understanding it should be "Yes"

Comment: What's the value of `$stock_return` and how on earth do you get `No` out put?

Comment: That code would _not_ show "No" but output a "_Undefined variable $stock_return in ..._" warning since you never assign anything to `$stock_return`. You assign "Stock returned" to `$vendor_name` twice. More on [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) from the manual

Answer (score 0):

The 1 equal sign (`=`) is used for assigning values, it is not used for comparisons.

Comparisons are made with `==` or `===`, that makes your `$stock_return === "Yes";` line incorrect as well because it looks like you want to assign a value to `$stock_return`

The difference between `==` and `===` is that

`==` is for testing if both values are equal, with php, a string '20' and an integer 20 are equal

`===` is more strict and will test the type as well so a string '20' is no longer equal to an integer 20

Your code should look something like this to be correct

```
$vendor_name = "Stock Returned";
if($vendor_name == "Stock Returned")
{
    $stock_return = "Yes";
}
else
{
    $stock_return = "No";
}
echo $stock_return;
```